# Make pom a synonym of pom.xml

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, synonym-request

I think the tag [pom](/questions/tagged/pom) should be a synonym of [pom.xml](/questions/tagged/pom.xml), since they are both the same thing, just one with the file extension.

Comment: You can [suggest a synonym](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pom/synonyms), no? Oh wait, you need enough rep in that tag...

Comment: Correct, I lack the rep in that tag.